# how to move a picture randomly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how can I move the ball randomly when I click the mouse with addEventListener
I tried this code but the picture didn't move . what is wrong with this code?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="work.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="work.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id = "frame" >
<div id = "net1"> </div>
<div id = "net2"> </div>
<div id = "centerPoint"> </div>
<div id = "centerLine"> </div>
<img src="SoccerBall.png" width="40" alt="Ball" class="moveBall">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

javascript code

```
var ball = document.querySelector('.moveBall');
function bbb(){

var ball = document.querySelector('.moveBall');

var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300); 
ball.style.left = x + 'px';
ball.style.top = y + 'px';
};

document.querySelector('#frame').addEventListener('click',bbb);
```

this is my css code:

```
     #frame{
         border:solid thick red;
         border-width:3px;
         padding-left:9px;
         padding-top:6px; 
         padding-bottom:6px;
         margin:2px;
         width:1220px;
         height:1000px;
         float:right;
         background-color:green;

      }


 .moveBall {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
     }
  #net1{

 background-color: lightgray;
 width: 400px;
 padding: 40px;
 margin: auto;

  }

 #net2{

 background-color: lightgray;
 width: 400px;
 padding:40px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:840px;
```

Comment: wrap it into window.addEventListener("load",function(){ ...

Comment: @Jonasw Why is that necessary?

Comment: @j08691 document.querySelector would probably fail, as the js is included way before the element

Comment: @Jonasw Ah yes, good catch. I didn't even see where he had included his .js file

Comment: What's in your CSS file?

Comment: how do i wrap it into window.addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

add  style `position:absolute` to the ball

```js
(function() {
  function bbb(){

   var ball = document.querySelector('.moveBall');
console.log(ball);
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300); 
   ball.style.left = x + 'px';
   ball.style.top = y + 'px';
 };
 
document.querySelector('#frame').addEventListener('click',bbb);

})();
```

```css
#frame{
   border:solid thick red;
   border-width:3px;
   padding-left:9px;
   padding-top:6px; 
   padding-bottom:6px;
   margin:2px;
   width:1220px;
   height:1000px;
   float:right;
   background-color:green;

}


.moveBall {
width:40px;
height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
  border-radius:50%;
  
  border:1px solid red;
 }
 
  #net1{ 
   background-color: lightgray;
   width: 400px;
   padding: 40px;
    margin: auto; 
  }

 #net2{ 
   background-color: lightgray;
   width: 400px;
   padding:40px;
   margin:auto;
   margin-top:840px;
 }
```

```html
<div id = "frame" >
  <div id = "net1"> </div>
  <div id = "net2"> </div>
  <div id = "centerPoint"> </div>
   <div id = "centerLine"> </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="40" alt="Ball" class="moveBall">
</div>
```

Comment: the ball is still not movien

Comment: @amir  try click on the image

Comment: still not workingand i want to click on the frame not on the ball picture

Comment: @amir click on the green background and you can seen the ball moving

Comment: i clicked on the  green background and the ball dont move at all

Comment: @amir I,m not sure what is the issue.For me it is moving .I have checked chrome and firefox

Comment: i get this error in my conso.logl : TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: @amir check if you have element `.moveBall`.Console variable  `ball` and check if you are getting value.Check my updated code

Comment: when i do that console.log(ball); nothing happened in the console i dont get any value

Comment: @amir make a js fidle with your exact  code.I will check that

Comment: @amir  My  snippet has same html code in your question.For me the image in changing to random position.Also I'm getting the image element in console.So please make the question more clear.or please post the exact code

Comment: when i remove the picture and only use the word "ball" its working and the word ball is moving but when i add   <img src="SoccerBall.png"  its not working and the picture dont move

Comment: @amir The ball is changing position in the fiddle also.So whats is your issue??

Comment: its working !!!!! the problem was that the script tag was in the head !! when i put the script tag in the end of the body its starts to work

Comment: @amir you have to put your js inside document.ready always.Anyway thanks